# Should copy&paste answers be this harshly rejected?

Tags: discussion

Yes, in the last few days I've copy-pasted (my own) an answer from another SO question.

I've done this only to help the user asking the question.

No, I cannot flag the question as duplicate, as not one of similar (3-5) questions have approved answers (most of them also mine).

I wonder: If the goal of SO is to help its users, why denying valid, yet correct answers? Should I change the wording of each answer a little so that it is not recognised as a duplicate? Should I force each of newbie SO "askers" to actually grasp the concept of Stack Overflow so that they accept the original answer, so that "duplicate question" flag can be used?

I don't know, this policy seems too harsh to me, especially given I have no possibility to appeal against the removal of my "new" answer by a moderator not considering all perspecives of the copypasted answer.

Comment: Afaik it doesn't have to be *accepted* ... just *upvoted*

Comment: And you may be a little confused as to the goal of SO. It's a Q/A repository. Individual help is a great byproduct of creation of the repository, but not its primary goal.

Comment: Are you not appealing the removal right now, by positing on Meta SO?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, I am. Yet it seems to be a too distant alternative - I cannot directly "vote" on the removal, I cannot contact the mod that removed the answer...

Comment: Maybe, you should just wait. I mean, you can flag the answer with a custom moderator flag, but I don't think that would endear you to the other moderators. Copying and pasting an answer from one question to another is bad juju. You should absolutely be tailoring your answers to each question's individual quirks, right after making sure there are no duplicate questions whose answers you can (in good faith) upvote, thereby making it a valid target for closure.

Comment: You can comment with a link to an existing answer if you're unable to vote for dupe. There's no need to copy-paste an answer, ever.

Comment: "*No, I cannot flag the question as duplicate, as not one of similar (3-5) questions have approved answers (most of them also mine).*" I'm not aware of any limitation to the duplicate system that relies answers to be approved. Or upvoted, or accepted. Or for there to even *be* answers, really - occasionally we flag a question as a duplicate when the user literally re-posts it within a short timeframe. Sometimes it's accidental, other times not but it's clearly *the same* question, even if neither has answers. Usually we don't flag a question with no answers as dupe otherwise but still.

Comment: @VLAZ Nonetheless, there is that restriction. i've run into it, myself, a few times same as the OP.

Comment: @CindyMeister OK, then I've not seen it. Perhaps it's something newer or only conditionally enforced (depending on what the conditions are). I've definitely flagged questions as dupes that are from the same author and had been reposted. Both intentionally and by mistake. In either cases there were no actual answers to the question. I'm pretty sure I've dupe voted for questions without an accepted answer. Can't remember if I've use a target with no upvoted answers, though.

Comment: @vlaz the conditions are (a) an upvoted answer or (b) a repost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! One of the main purposes of SO is to be a collection of useful questions and their answers. If the same question gets answered at multiple places it is far more difficult to find. That's why duplicate questions are supposed to be closed, and duplicate answers shall not exist.

> No, I cannot flag the question as duplicate, as not one of similar (3-5) questions have approved answers

But you could *recommend* the other Q&A, and someone else might find your answer useful, upvote it, then you can vote to close ...